# Does it matter whether a key in a Javascript object is written within double quotes?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var people = {"name": "Akshar"};
var friends = {name: "Prahlad"};
```

As shown in the sample code above. I have two objects where one has the 'name' key within double quotes and the other one is without it. When I printed them to the console with dot or bracket notation, it printed the values for both without any issue. So does it make a difference whether I write the keys with the doubles quotes or not? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: You **need** the quotes (single or double) when the property name does not constitute a valid identifier (like, if you couldn't use the name as a variable name), but otherwise it makes no difference.

Comment: No it does not, it does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Pointy …with the exception of numeric literals, which are not valid identifier names but also don't need to be quoted as property names.

Comment: @Bergi oo yes that's true. (I don't think I've ever done that personally.)